# add icon to activity bar in visual studio code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to VSC extension development.

I started with the extension hello world and I want to add an icon to the activity bar and get a notification when it is clicked.

I add these lines to package.json

```
"viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
                {
                    "id": "package-explorer",
                    "title": "Package Explorer",
                    "icon": "media/my.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
```

I copied these lines from VSC sample treeView (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample)

The icon is also copied from the same repository.

When I run the extension, I am not getting any icon in the activity bar. What should I do so this icon appears in the activity bar and how can I be notified if it is clicked?

Comment: do you have any view in this container, do you have the example working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also specify a `"views"` item that matches the `id` of your `viewContainer`

Try adding the following right after the `"viewsContainers"` object in the `"contributes"` section of `package.json`

```
"views": {
    "package-explorer": [
        {
            "id": "VIEW_ID",
            "name": "VIEW_NAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make sure the icon path is set correctly to an existing image - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73930348/1461862