# vsCode extension not showing up on ActivityBar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating my second vscode extension, its a Language Service extension (that has both server and client side)

I need to know how to make my extension have an icon shown on the ActivityBar and when clicked and I need to show a very basic panel with just two labels and textbox inputs (this is how Metals extension looks)

[image]

I have checked these documents without any luck

- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/activity-bar
- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/views#view-containers

I also just found this answer but the icon is not being shown on the left ActivityBar
[add icon to activity bar in visual studio code extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879075/add-icon-to-activity-bar-in-visual-studio-code-extension)

Here is my contributes section from the packages.json if you need any other information let me in the comments

```json
"contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "Example configuration",
            "properties": {
                "navCode.maxNumberOfProblems": {
                    "scope": "resource",
                    "type": "number",
                    "default": 100,
                    "description": "Controls the maximum number of problems produced by the server."
                },
                "navCode.trace.server": {
                    "scope": "window",
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "off",
                        "messages",
                        "verbose"
                    ],
                    "default": "off",
                    "description": "Traces the communication between VS Code and the language server."
                }
            }
        },
        "viewsContainers": {
            "activitybar": [
                {
                    "id": "package-explorer",
                    "title": "Package Explorer",
                    "icon": "media/my.svg"
                }
            ]
        },
        "views": {
            "package-explorer": [
                {
                    "id": "package-dependencies",
                    "name": "Dependencies"
                },
                {
                    "id": "package-outline",
                    "name": "Outline"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared your `viewContainer` and the `view` itself in the `packages.json` but still your extension is not showing up in the ActiviyBar the reason can be that the path to the icons is wrong or that the images do not exist

I created a images folder with a nav-code-logo.png
then I used that path in the packages.json

`"icon": "images/nav-code-logo.png"`

And now it works.

[image]